# Ruby - 2 dimension array search

Tags: ruby

I have the following 2 dimension array

```
data = [
 [5014031, nil], [5014032, nil], [5014033, 0], 
 [5014034, nil], [3014035, 1], [5014036, 1], 
 [5014037, 2], [5014038, nil], [5014039, 2], 
 [5014040, nil], [2014041, nil], [3014042, 2]
]
```

When I know the value of the 1st integer of one of these arrays e.g. 5014034, what would be the most efficient way to gain the next integer value where the 2nd element matches to nil? (e.g. I would expect 5014038 to be returned)

Thanks
Scott

Comment: Most efficient way to do this query once or most efficient to do this repeatedly? Is this array sorted by 1st integer?

Comment: Hi @ChristopherOezbek It's only going to happen once per page request and the array can have 1000's of entries and there's no sort.

Comment: Will the array be the same for all page requests? Or will each request operate on another array? Because if all requests operate on the same array then it would make sense to use a different data structure that is optimized for reading the data. And another question if the input was `5014040` what is then the "next integer"? `2014041` because it is next in the array? Or or `nil` because there is no bigger integer than `5014040` with a 2nd element being `nil`?

Comment: @spickermann All pages will have different arrays and if the known id was 5014040 the next integer would be 2014041 as it has the next nil.

Comment: What do you mean by all pages having different arrays? Does that mean that all users operate on the same data when they request the same page? Is the array generated with data from the database? Would it be possible to write an optimized database query instead?

Comment: Yes it would be possible, but testing to see if processing without a second query is more efficient.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way, using `#drop_while` and `#find_index`:

```
data = [
  [5014031, nil], [5014032, nil], [5014033, 0],
  [5014034, nil], [5014035, 1  ], [5014036, 1],
  [5014037, 2  ], [5014038, nil], [5014039, 2],
  [5014040, nil], [5014041, nil], [5014042, 2]
]

remaining_arr = data.drop_while { |arr| arr[0] != 5014034 }[1..]
next_int = remaining_arr[remaining_arr.find_index { |arr| arr[1].nil? }][0]
```

Alternatively:

```
data
  .drop_while { |x| x[0] != 5014034 }[1..]
  .drop_while { |x| !x[1].nil? }[0][0]
# => 5014038
```

Comment: `remaining_arr.find { |a, b| b.nil? }[0]` or `remaining_arr.rassoc(nil)[0]` works too. You also have to remove the first element from `remaining_arr` to exclude it from the 2nd search. (otherwise you'll return `[5014034, nil]` instead of `[5014038, nil]`)

Comment: Thanks! Incorporated this suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You could slice the array into two when the first element in the inner array matches `5014034`. Extract the second resulting array and use find to look for the inner array whose second element is nil:

```
arr
  .slice_when { |a, _| a == 5014034 } # #<Enumerator: ...>
  .to_a                               # [[[5014031, nil], [5014032, nil], [5014033, 0], [5014034, nil]], [[5014035, 1], [5014036, 1], [5014037, 2], [5014038, nil], [5014039, 2], [5014040, nil], [5014041, nil], [5014042, 2]]]
  [1]                                 # [[5014035, 1], [5014036, 1], [5014037, 2], [5014038, nil], [5014039, 2], [5014040, nil], [5014041, nil], [5014042, 2]]
  .find { |_, b| b.nil? }             # [5014038, nil]
  [0]                                 # 5014038
```

Notice this method chaining might fail if there's no array in arr whose first object inside matches `5014034`, and/or the same for `find`.

Answer (score 0):

If sorted then the following might be faster

```rb
data = [
 [5014031, nil], [5014032, nil], [5014033, 0], 
 [5014034, nil], [5014035, 1], [5014036, 1], 
 [5014037, 2], [5014038, nil], [5014039, 2], 
 [5014040, nil], [5014041, nil], [5014042, 2]
]

start_element = data.bsearch_index{ |a| a[0] >= 5014034 }

if start_element == nil || data[start_element] != 5014034
  puts "not found"
else
  data.slice((start_element+1)..).find { |a| a[1] == nil }[0]
end
```